# Pandas: Using asfreq

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-analysis

I have a cyclical time series in mm:ss.0 format that looks like

```
59:58.5
59:58.7
59:59.1
00:00.0
00:00.1
00:00.2
```

(This repeats for a while with no hour marker, i.e. it goes on for about five or six hours)

What I want is to split the entire series into 30 second intervals, preferably using `asfreq`. This seems like a two-part problem: first, I need to split the time period into 30 second intervals, which is harder than it appears since I don't have an hour label (is there an easy way to add this in Excel?). Next, I need to actually use `asfreq` to split the data into 30 second frequencies.

For simplicity's sake, I took a 1-hour sample of my data and wrote a test program to try separating that subset into 30-second intervals.

My data is something like

```
0:00:05.2   46
0:00:05.3   46
0:00:05.9   46
0:00:06.0   46
0:00:06.1   46
0:00:06.4   47
0:00:06.9   47
```

And my code is

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv',index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%M:%S.%f')
df.index.get_duplicates()
df.Data = df.Data.asfreq(str(30)+'S',method='pad')
```

The error I keep getting is 
    ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Anyone know how to approach this and/or how to split cyclical data?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split it, then use `groupby`. Each group will then hold the data for that group only.

```
grouped = df.groupby(<time column or index>)
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name, group)
```

The reason you are getting the said error is because there are non-unique values in the index. How will Pandas figure out which value goes to which index in your line: `df.Data = df.Data.asfreq(str(30)+'S',method='pad')`?

Comment: I don't think there are any non-unique values. I used the Excel "filter" function to get rid of any duplicate times and did more than a cursory check on my data to ensure that I didn't have repeats. For what it's worth, I took a small subset of the data (about 200 samples) and tried the function there and was able to obtain an output. For the `groupby`, I wanted to go the `asfreq` route because I genuinely wanted something every 30th second rather than just having them in groups

Comment: Didn't understand what you want to do. Instead of proposing a solution (`asfreq` in this case) can you provide a small chunk of your data, and the required output in your question? We can then pick an algorithm that goes from the input dataset to the output dataset. Just a this is what I have... This is what I need... would be perfect.